# Selecting the top row in each group in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns - region and profession

```
region   |  profession
India    |  IT
India    |  IT
US       |  HR
US       |  HR
India    |  HR
```

I want to display the most popular profession in every region. the output should only be

```
Region | Profession
India  | IT
US     | HR
```

Comment: I thought of grouping the table by regions and then taking a count of the distinct professions per group but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please add example query(s) & result(s) so we can address what you need to know from what you seem to know. Right now you are asking for a solution tout court.

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get a `count` of the results per group.  Then you need to establish an order per group -- mysql can do this with `user-defined variables`.

Here's an example:

```
select region, profession
from (
  select region, profession, 
    @rn:=if(@oldregion=region,@rn+1,0) rn,
    @oldregion:=region
  from (
    select region, profession, count(*) cnt
    from yourtable
    group by region, profession) t, (select @rn:=0, @oldregion='') t2
  order by region, cnt desc) t3
where rn = 0
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c9e2/1)

---

Here's another solution using a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct region, (
    select profession
    from yourtable t2
    where t.region = t2.region
    group by region, profession
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1) as profession
from yourtable t
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c9e2/3)